# Compound component not restoring state of views

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making a compound component, with a button.

```
class CreateConfigNodeView : ConstraintLayout {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    loadLayout()
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    loadLayout()
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    loadLayout()
}

private fun loadLayout() {
    inflate(context, R.layout.compound_view_layout, this)
}
```

With a basic layout like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/inline_create_operator_controls"
tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/aid_for_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</merge>
```

I successfully set the text of the button(/textview/whatever) programatically. When I rotate the screen the button text gets reset to whatever its set to in the xml.

I implemented onSaveInstanceState/onRestore and manually stored the text of the component and set it again, it works that way but that feels wrong.

I was under the impression that the components would handle their own states. Have I done something wrong with the constructors / inflation maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView` (and all its subclasses, so `Button` too) does not automatically save the text on rotation, unless `freezesText` is set to `true`.
From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText):

> If set, the text view will include its current complete text inside of its frozen icicle in addition to meta-data such as the current cursor position. By default this is disabled; it can be useful when the contents of a text view is not stored in a persistent place such as a content provider. For EditText it is always enabled, regardless of the value of the attribute.

So what you have to do basically is:

```
<Button 
     ... 
     android:freezesText="true" />
```

Comment: Do you know a lifecycle callback when the frozen text is set to the component? I've checked constructor and onRestoreInstanceState (of compound component) and in both these it remains unset. It is working and it is set eventually, I just wonder when.

Comment: It is done inside `TextView`, in `onRestoreInstanceState`, here the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#5448